# Reading variable with inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly

I'm wondering, is there a limitation on reading input variables based on the actual instruction?

I'm trying to read an input variable in inline assembly for a `.rept` directive to repeat an instruction `x` number of times.

However, the assembler complains with:
`Error: negative count for REPT - ignored`

Here's my approach:

```c
const int x = 42;
__asm__ volatile (".rept %[in]" :: [in] "m" (x));
__asm__ volatile (".endr");
```

Trying to load the variable value into a register works just as expected:

```c
int function(void) {
    const int x = 42;
    __asm__ volatile ("mov %[in], %%eax" :: [in] "m" (x));
    __asm__ volatile ("ret");
}
```

returns `42`, disassembly looks as expected.

I tried writing this in assembly to see if a constant can be used with `.rept` directive and it does so indeed

```
global _start

section .data
    nvalue  equ     39

section .text

_start:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp,    rsp

    %rep nvalue
        nop
    %endrep

    mov     rax,    60
    mov     rdi,    nvalue
    syscall
```

Disassembly looks as expected:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000401000 <_start>:
  401000:       55                      push   rbp
  401001:       48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  401004:       90                      nop
  ...
  40102d:       90                      nop
  40102e:       b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x3c
  401033:       bf 2a 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x2a
  401038:       0f 05                   syscall
```

Am I confusing `.rept` with `%rep` and do they not represent identical operation?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.rept` is a directive to the assembler to repeat code. It is not going to take a memory reference, which you specify with `"m"`. The compiler probably writes the memory reference as something like `-4(%rbp)`, hence the error message about a negative value. I do not think GCC or Clang has a constraint for this. You can use `"i"` for an immediate operand, but that comes with the marker that denotes an immediate operand in an instruction, `$` in Intel assembly, so it puts `$42` in the assembly, whereas you need a plain `42`. There may not be a way to do this.

Comment: You can't safely `ret` in an `asm()` statement, except as part of the body of an `__attribute__((naked))` function.  (And in that case, the entire body has to be a Basic Asm statement; no input/output constraints.  i.e. it's a way to let the compiler do name mangling while you write the whole function body in asm.)  Other than that, you can't `ret`; that will break when the compiler inlines your function into some caller.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Looking at the disassembly of `int function()`, I can see that `[rbp-0x4]` is indeed the product of the memory reference. Thank you very much for your explanation Eric.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for pointing that out Peter! Indeed, I just tried returning the return value of `function()` from `main()` and all hell broke loose.

Comment: Similarly, if you write a register in an Extended `asm` statement, you need to mention it as a clobber or an output operand.  i.e. your asm that writes EAX steps on the compiler's toes, and you should expect breakage.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: There is, with the `c` modifier that omits the `$`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, an `i` operand will normally be inserted with a leading `$` sign, which is correct as an immediate operand in AT&T syntax but not good for an assembler directive like `.rept`.  You can suppress this with the `c` modifier, see [Section 6.47.2.8 of the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm):

```
void many_nops(void) {
    const int num = 42;
    asm(".rept %c0 ; nop ; .endr" : : "i" (num));
}
```

This will inline 42 `nop` instructions.  Of course this will only work if `num` can be folded as a compile-time constant; in particular you must compile with optimization for it to work.

[Try on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8zqvxqE8h)

You could also use Intel asm syntax with `-masm=intel`, in which constants don't get a leading `$` in the first place.

Note that there are a number of other problems with your inline asm (you can't `ret` from inline asm, shouldn't split code between multiple `asm` statements, etc.) so you might want to start by reading some of the FAQs at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info.

The issue with `.rept` versus `%rep`: the first is the correct syntax for the GNU assembler `gas` which is normally used for assembling GCC output, and the second is for the `nasm` assembler.